# Localize Bootstrap date-time-picker to support multiple languages, but return an english date time value after selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

The app that I'm working on supports localization for several languages, and so when I initialize the datetimepicker in the app, I pass in the current language being used as follows:

```
datetimepicker({
    locale: languageObj.language,
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['YYYY-MM-DD'],
    icons: {
        previous: 'btn-chevron-prev',
        next: 'btn-chevron-next',
    }
});
```

However, when I get the `.val()` of this datetimepicker input after a user has selected a date, the value is also returned as the translated date time.  What I am hoping to do is visualize to the user the translated version of the date time picker, but return the english, default translation of the selected date when I get the value of the date time picker. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR, just show me the code

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/L86op193/) showing 2 different approaches.

### Explanation

**Approach #1**

The docs describe [a `date` option](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#date):

> Returns the component's model current date, a moment object or null if not set.

At the top of the same page there is a note about how to use those options:

> Note All options are accessed via the data attribute e.g. `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").OPTION()`

So, wherever you are using `.val()`, eg maybe something like:

```
// Localised value, not what you want
var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker').val();
```

Instead, use the `date()` option.  Remember `date()` returns a moment object, so [you can format it](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) however you want, eg `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**Approach #2**

The docs describe [the `dp.change` event](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/):

> Fired when the date is changed ...
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> e = {
>    date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>    oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> }
> ```

So whenever the user selects a date, we can use that event to get the date they chose.

```
$('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function(e) {
    // We can now access e.date and e.oldDate, both moment objects
    var selectedDate = e.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    // ... do something with selectedDate ...
});
```

You can see both approaches in action, with explanatory comments, in [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/L86op193/).

Comment: Sorry I did not answer until now, but this answer absolutely worked. All I needed to do was do the:
```var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```
solution.  All I was looking for was a function that this datepicker had for converting all dates no matter what language they were localized to back to an english format.